# Why order by deosn't work when I use count()?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Here is my query:

```
SELECT count(1) all_requests_num, date_time
FROM requests
WHERE user_id = :id
ORDER BY date_time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

As you can see, I've ordered rows based on `date_time` descendingly. But the result of `date_time` isn't the biggest value. Why? How can I fix it?

---

Here is a simplified example:

```
// requests
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | other_cols |  date_time  |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 1  | ...        | 1517045060  |
| 2  | ...        | 1517045061  |
| 3  | ...        | 1517045062  |
| 4  | ...        | 1517045063  |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

The expected result for `date_time` is `1517045063`, but my query above returns `1517045060`.

Comment: what do you mean by *isn't the biggest value* ?? can you show your output ?

Comment: Your syntax seems off in the column list for starters. Also,if you use an aggregating function (ie count), it causes an implied group by (you'll only get one row returned). Edit your question and add an example of what your query returns, and what you expect.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I **want** one row returned. That's why I've also used `limit 1`

Comment: @Ravi Edited ....

Comment: Just for grins and giggles, did you try changing the DESC to ASC?

Comment: With the order by, you'll get the last value in columns not in a group by clause. DESC will have to lowest value last. ASC will have the highest value last.

Comment: @SloanThrasher using either `DESC` or `ASC` returns the same result.

Comment: The count(1) forces an implied group by, the other columns in the select are indeterminate so 1 row is returned in the resultset which is then sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is using a (mis) feature of MySQL that would not work in any other database.  `COUNT()` is an aggregation function.  Without a `GROUP BY`, it turns the query into an aggregation query that returns one row.  The `LIMIT 1` is redundant -- remove it and see what I mean.

You can get the maximum `date_time` in several ways using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT date_time
FROM requests
WHERE user_id = :id
ORDER BY date_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

That doesn't give you the count.  For that, use just an aggregation query (as suggested by Martin):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MAX(date_time)
FROM requests
WHERE user_id = :id;
```

Happily, this structure can be used for all users at once:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*), MAX(date_time)
FROM requests
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is using `MAX()` on `date_time` column:

```
SELECT count(1) all_requests_num, MAX(date_time) date_time
FROM requests
WHERE user_id = :id
```